# Switching Firefox snap package from beta to stable channel

Tags: firefox, snap, beta

I'm on Firefox beta channel (which is 60.0b10). How can I switch back to the stable channel? I've already searched, but I found nothing about it.

Answer (score 3):

The beta channel of the Firefox snap package is currently version 60.0b10, but the stable channel of the Firefox snap package is currently version  59.0.2-1, the same as the default Firefox apt package (version 59.0.2). So uninstall the Firefox snap package and install the default Firefox package instead. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove --channel=beta firefox    
sudo apt install firefox
```

After installation the channel for a particular snap may be changed during a refresh:

```
 sudo snap refresh --channel=stable firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 `--channel` can't be used anymore.

```
sudo snap remove --channel=beta firefox  
error: unknown flag `channel'
```

You can simply use the **alias** from `snap list`:

```
sudo snap remove firefox_beta
```